# Disambiguate the [union] tag

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The word "union" can refer to at least 3 different things:

1. A union in the C language
2. A union in SQL
3. A union in set theory

Currently the tag wiki ([union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/union)) is about SQL unions, but [a search for [union][c]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/union+c) gives 124 results. A [search for [union][sql]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+union) gives 334 results. Questions about unions in set theory seem to be more scarce, but can be found by combining with [set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/set), [intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersection), or similar set-theoretic terms.

I believe these 3 meanings need to be disambiguated.

Comment: How is a `union` in SQL different from that in set theory?  a C `union` is obviously entirely different and should indeed be disambiguated.

Comment: @Servy good point, though in actuality they are quite different since SQL unions aren't quite as formally defined as set theory unions, plus you don't really have syntax-related questions about set theory unions but you easily could for SQL ones

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo In my mind Union in SQL is a slightly imperfect implemention that is attempting to emulate a set union.  Most of the imperfections are related to the fact that tables/queries in SQL aren't technically sets, they're just *close*.  In my mind these two concepts are "close enough" to be in the same tag.  Most implementations of a `union` in any non-theoretical context are likely to have some slight deviation from the mathematical definition.  I don't think each one should have it's own tag though.

Comment: @Servy The `union` keyword in SQL is indeed an application of set-theoretic union. I feel it is specific enough, and used often enough, to warrant it's own tag.

Comment: Please take a look at the tags: [tag:unions] (mostly C-style untagged-unions), [tag:discriminated-union] (same concept with a discriminator), and the other tags with "union" in their name.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Other languages have untagged unions too. Also, you probably want to remember [tag:discriminated-union] too.

Comment: As of today, @timrau is going through historical C posts changing `union` to `unions`

Answer (score 5):

Suggestions:

- re-tag [[c][union]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c+union) and [[c++][union]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20union) combinations into [c-union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-union)
- re-tag [[sql][union]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+union) combinations into [sql-union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-union)
- re-tag [[set][union]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/set+union) and [[set][intersection]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersection+union) combinations into [set-union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/set-union)

After all that, the tag should be banned.

Comment: I don't think the tag gets enough abuse to be banned, though you might decide to put it on your list for regular cleanup. Also, what about e.g. LINQ?

Comment: Are you saying that because banning currently requires a dev from SE?

Comment: How about [tag:linq-union]? Is `[lang-union]` not comfortable?

Comment: LINQ is not a language but a feature/library of some languages. Anyway, you don't really want to separate them by their language, but by the concept, so better go for [tag:discriminated-union] (exists) and [tag:untagged-union] (does not exist). Also, take a look into [tag:unions] and the other tags including "union".

Comment: Yes, I didn't think hard enough before proposing `[lang-union]`. I actually wanted to also propose `[tech-union]` or something like that.

Comment: Looks like [tag:unions] is mostly used for C-related Questions, though I saw a champion that actually did a lot of re-tags to that effect, perhaps guide by the tag wiki. It's a less-than-ideal approach of course, and not too sustainable.

Comment: Well, we get mostly SQL and data-structure, much less set-theory. Also, data-structure is divided into untagged-union and [tag:discriminated-union], with the first used to implement the second.

Comment: There's a C++ function called `set_union` and that tag seems mostly used for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed that this is still a problem some 8 years later.

Apparently [union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/union) was originally made for the purpose of SQL UNION. Then in 2014 someone made the decision (in [union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/union) tag wiki) to say that C and C++ questions should use the questionable [unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unions) tag instead.

This is very ambiguous. The C and C++ keyword is `union`, singularis. Out of 4747 [union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/union) questions, we have:

- 2152 questions tagged [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql).
- 89 questions tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).
- 70 questions tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).
- 2440 questions not tagged with any of the above. Including pretty much every known programming language out there and just a minority of them are about SQL UNION.

It's hard to say how many that are about mathematical unions, though there are for example 38 questions tagged [union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/union) + [intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersection).

As for [unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unions), out of 1392 questions supposedly about the C and C++ keyword:

- 13 are tagged SQL.
- 689 are tagged C.
- 627 are tagged C++.

Those posts not tagged with any of the above seem to again be about misc languages, though a lot of them also seem to be SQL or C questions where someone just didn't use the language tag.

---

I don't really know what to do with these tags.

I think it's pretty pointless burninate [union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/union), it's a vast tag and it is used for so many diverse purposes. It's just one of those broad, vague tags. Same thing with [unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unions). Neither tag is used as the respective tag wiki describes, probably because the names are so generic.

Maybe a mod could just mass-delete these tags and then have them blacklisted... but they are pretty harmless. They just don't add anything of value by themselves. There's the extra [burnination criteria rule](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/584518) "Is the tag causing a fairly large amount of harm?" No, not really.

They might in combination with a language tag though. So maybe one option would be to make [union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/union) and [unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unions) synonyms, then add a tag usage wiki saying that the tag should be used together with the relevant language tag.

Comment: Not for nothing, but this kind of ambiguity is the reason that we can use multiple tags on a question, and [union][c] works perfectly well as a search term.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yep, why my conclusion is that we probably just should edit the tag wiki to allow broader use than SQL.