# Why are my tag edits getting rejects?

Tags: discussion, support, rejected-edits

There are two very similar tags [union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/union) and [unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unions); while the tag wikis are clear enough [the tag themselves are ambiguous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253379/disambiguate-the-union-tag).

[union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/union):

> Use this tag only for questions about UNION, a keyword of the SQL language for combining the results of multiple SQL queries. Use [union-all] for the UNION-ALL keyword. Use the tag [unions] for unions in C, C++, and similar languages.

[unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unions):

> The plural of a keyword in the C family of languages for declaring a union data type.

Because these tag are ambiguous they are misused, leading to a need for regular cleanup. A few days ago I saw that there were ~30 questions tagged with [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)[union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/union), and decided to help clean up by re-tagging some of them. I have suggested edits to almost all of them, most of which were approved, but there were quite a few which got one reject, and some where rejected outright.

On January 9, 2019; I suggested 14 edits:

"A" represents "approve", "R" represents "reject"

1. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21881730. **Approved: A A**
2. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21881819. **Approved: A A**
3. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21881952. **Approved: A A**
4. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21882259. **Approved: A A**
5. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21882483. **Approved: A A**
6. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21882492. **Approved: A A**
7. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21882498. **Approved: R A A**
8. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21882545. **Approved: A A**
9. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21882813. **Approved: R A A**
10. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21882854. **Rejected: R R**
11. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21883115. **Approved: R A A**
12. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21883154. **Approved: A A**
13. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21884709. **Approved: A A**
14. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21884761. **Rejected: A R R**

What concerns me is that my main intention was to fix the incorrect tagging; however it seems to be the edits where pretty much only the tags where edited which got one or more rejects. As you can see in the edit comment, I clearly stated the intent of my edits. The tags used where obviously wrong, yet reviewers still rejected the change. Why?

Comment: You had two rejections out of 14 suggested edits? That's not something to be particularly concerned.

Comment: And the two rejections are: one on a "tag only" edit, which a some users frown upon for "suggested" edits; and the other one changed the error formatting from code-blocks to block-quotes... something not everybody agrees with.

Comment: Other than the incorrect formatting change in the last edit, your text change should have included removing 'are' between those last two blocks; it no longer makes sense for it to be there.

Answer (score 11):

They were probably rejected because the reviewers thought that there were other improvements to the posts that you didn't make.

I know you are editing to fix the tags, but you should look at the whole post and see if there's anything else you can fix there - spelling, grammar, formatting etc.

This will make it more likely that your edits will be accepted.

Comment: If you take a look through the edits you will see that in all of them I fixed as much as I could, in the body and title as well as the tags. In those tag-only edits or nearly tag-only edits there was nothing or very little else to fix.